# function call in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How to call a function in select statement of sql server query?

```
select name,function output() from tab where
name='samp'
```

In this above query how to call a function

Comment: select name,output() from tab where
name='samp'

Comment: where is your function? are you getting error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just create the query shown below and Execute it...

```
SELECT
   name,
   output(params)
FROM
   tab
WHERE
   nam='samp'
```

Answer (score 2):

simply

```
select name, output() from tab where name='samp'
```

For once forget that this function is created by you and think this to be an in-built function like `Count()` or `Max()`. How do we call them?

```
select Count(*) from tab
```